# How to fix Incompatible pointer types returning 'RecipeCell *' from a function with result type 'UITableViewCell *'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm getting into the developing world and Xcode came up with this:

> Incompatible pointer types returning 'RecipeCell *' from a function with result type 'UITableViewCell *'

I was wondering how could it be fixed. I already tried to rename it to UITableViewCell but nothing changes (plus doing so, gives me an error as well).

```
//
//  RecipeList.m
//  Mama's Recipies
//
//  Created by Santiago Rosenblatt on 8/23/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Tuckyapps. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RecipeList.h"
#import "RecipeCell.h"

@interface RecipeList ()

@end

@implementation RecipeList

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)InterfaceOrientation
{
    return (InterfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    RecipeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecipeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in objects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (RecipeCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return cell; //here I get the warning
}

@end
```

here it is RecipeCell.h:

```
//  RecipeCell.h
//  Mama's Recipies
//
//  Created by Santiago Rosenblatt on 8/23/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Tuckyapps. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RecipeCell : UITableViewController

@end
```

When edited to declare the class as UITableViewCell, Xcode give 3 ARC Semantic Issues:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style]; //here it says "No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell" declares the selector 'initWithStyle:'
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; //No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell" declares the selector 'viewDidLoad'

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; //No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell" declares the selector 'didReceiveMemoryWarning'
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: What is your declaration of the RecipeCell class? Does it inherit from UITableViewCell? - please edit your question to include RecipeCell.h

Comment: Where?  Did you edit the question?

Comment: Sorry, now it is, my bad. Does it give you any idea?

Answer (score 2):

`RecipeCell` must be a `UITableViewCell` subclass, not a `UITableViewController` subclass, so its declaration should be

```
//  RecipeCell.h
//  Mama's Recipies
//
//  Created by Santiago Rosenblatt on 8/23/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Tuckyapps. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RecipeCell : UITableViewCell

@end
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the warning issue, however, no i have 3 ARC sematic issues...

Comment: which are?  (Tip - Check for missing *)

Comment: Delete those three methods.  You don't need them for a tableViewCell class - they are view controller methods

Comment: Negative, now the screen is black, so there should be something else

Comment: It now compiles but there are obviously other issues in your program, unrelated to the custom cell.